# htaccess redirects affect administrator page on Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have a task - all somestuff.html/ pages with trailing slash must redirect to somestuff.html and all other pages without a trailing slash must redirect to add a trailing slash (e.g. /mypage must redirect to /mypage/). I have accomplished the task but now /administrator/ page returns 404 page. I tried to exclude the /administrator/ page but its not working:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#this part breaks the admin panel entry

RewriteRule ^([^.]+).html/ http://somedomain.com/$1\.html [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$

#trying to exclude administrator page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator/

RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]

#end of part that breaks the admin panel entry

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or maybe offer some different solution to acocmplish the redirecting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+).html/ http://logosstudy.ru/$1\.html [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```